# Почему при сохранении объекта с @IdClass его идентификаторы приравниваются null?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, jpa, orm

Есть такой код:

**BasicIssueDto**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "basic_issues")
public class BasicIssueDto {

    @Id
    private String key;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "basic_issue_key")
    private List<WorklogDto> worklogs;

}
```

**WorklogDto**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@IdClass(WorklogPk.class)
@Table(name = "worklogs")
public class WorklogDto {

    @Id
    private String basicIssueKey;

    @Id
    private Integer monthNumber;

    @Column(name = "time_spent_minutes")
    private Integer timeSpentMinutes;

}
```

**WorklogPk**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WorklogPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "basic_issue_key")
    private String basicIssueKey;

    @Column(name = "month_number")
    private Integer monthNumber;

}
```

А вот так я сохраняю BasicIssueDto:

```
session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(basicIssue);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Всем объектам WorklogDto я задаю id сам. Но почему-то при их сохранении hibernate выставляет id как (null, 0). В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Похоже, проблема не в @IdClass, а в неправильном мапинге. Но в чем дело не могу понять.

Comment: У сущности не может быть два идентификатора (`WorklogDto`), два поля помеченных аннотацией `@Id`

Comment: @notaProgrammer Может, т.к. это составной ключ. Для этого специально указана аннотация IdClass.